# Email, Text Messages, What's app

Tags: sms, email, whatsapp-messenger

Is there any way to get all messages in one application. I use 5 email accounts, text messaging and WhatsApp. I dont' want to have to go to 3 different folders when I get 3 different types of messages.

Is there any application, or way to set up my Galaxy S3 to get all messages in one place?

thanks

Comment: also, my emails are gmail, hotmail and exchange...

Comment: Why don't the Notifications work for you?

Comment: For what it's worth, I've now seen a number of people online lamenting that their Android device doesn't gather incoming messages the way their dearly departed BlackBerry did. Android just does things differently. I don't even know if it would be possible to create such an app.

Comment: Note, of course, that the stock email app should be able to connect to all of your email accounts, including Gmail, so those messages you can at least get into one place.

Comment: thanks, yes it connects to all my accounts, but I also want text and What's app in the same spot..so all my notifications come in one place. The Notifications work, but I still have to go to different folders to read the email, then to a different spot to read the text messages, and a 3rd spot to read the What's App messages. Too many clicks for my liking ;)

Comment: The BlackBerry Priv (BB's first Android phone) has a Hub.

Answer (score 1):

You can get most of that if you buy into the Google ecosystem.

I use Gmail for all of my email. I have several addresses. Those non-Gmail addresses I have are auto-forwarded (or pulled via POP3) into my Gmail inbox. I have Gmail set up to send as any of those addresses.

I use Google Voice and only ever give out that number. Any SMS messages sent to my number are forwarded to my Gmail. I can respond to those message by replying to the email message.

Voicemail, similar, is sent to my Gmail. While I can't listen to the voice message right in the email client on Android, it's just a hop and a skip over to the Google Voice app. In any case, I usually just use the automatic transcription to gauge whether I want to call the person back or not.

Comment: oh, my..it takes long enough to get my emails..I'm not forwarding them too.. ;) I would prefer just to get all notifications in one spot, like my BB used to have. Makes sense to not have to set more things up.

Comment: You can always get to the individual apps (gmail, sms etc) via notifications.  This is probably as close as you're going to get.

Comment: I've tried the app Executive Assistant and it's pretty good, but missing the ability to add other messaging applications, like What's App

Answer (score 0):

Try [Contacts +](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.contapps.android&hl=en) from the play store.It is powered with text messaging, WhatsApp, Facebook, Twitter and much more - all in one place.

Answer (score -1):

You have to switch to Blackberry to have the Blackberry HUB or you can try the [HUB for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.emsi.hub).